# Who can please recommend some PCB Manufacturers?

Tags: pcb

Who can please recommend some PCB Manufacturers?Better with much details, such as the delivery time, the minimum quantity, the mode of transport, etc.
Now I am in China, the search engine can search out a lot of manufacturers but I have not used before and don't know which one is better so I want someone with experience to recommend to me.
I want to buy 10pcb, 2 layers, 50 * 50
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Google is your friend.

Comment: You usually get what you pay for.

Comment: It is impossible to recommend anybody without knowing where you are, how many PCBs you want for example.  If you know other people nearby who have had boards made I'd ask them for recommendations otherwise try an internet search engine as suggested in another comment.  This question will probably be closed soon as buying recommendations are off topic on this site.

Comment: EE.SE is not a recommendation platform. You'll get downvote(s) for this and probably your question will be closed. Anyway, I personally recommend you to talk to some electronic equipment manufacturers because they know how to find a PCB manufacturer based on needs. I'm sure they will be happy to help you.

Answer (score 3):

There's a [site](https://pcbshopper.com/) that compares prices from different manufacturers. This could be a good place to start. Keep in mind that it searches 25 manufacturers (listed on the site) so there could be better prices elsewhere.